# requested type dbtype.string was not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Dim objParam As DbParameter
objParam = New SqlParameter
objParam.DbType = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(DbType), "DbType.String"), DbType)
```

The error I get is: requested type dbtype.string was not found.  Why do I get this error?

I realise I can do this:

objParam.DbType =DbType.String

Comment: What does your enum look like?

Comment: @Rick, i don't understand your question. Dbtype is an enum that is part of the .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the DbType text in the second param of [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 objParam.DbType = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(DbType), "String"), DbType)
```